# Were the Force trees related?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-clone-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Clone Wars* episode *Voices*, there was an ancient tree that grew in a courtyard of the Jedi Temple on Coruscant. The tree was Force-sensitive and it was eventually removed by Darth Sidious.

In *The Last Jedi*, another ancient Force tree had grown on the temple island of Ahch-To. The hollow trunk served as a library chamber of sacred books of the Jedi, and was probably connected to the Force, too. This tree was destroyed in a fire ignited by the Grand Master Yoda himself.

[image]

Were these two Force trees related somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, force trees are important and related. So important, and so related, that the emperor kept the two remaining sprouts of the Coruscant temple tree on a very secret complex.

The trees are used to train new force sensitive users into enterting in contact with the force in a safe environement, to most probably is a pure force element that has no light/darkness on it.

Poe Dameron is related to the Yavin IV force tree, his mother helped luke rescue the living sprouts.
(canon comic, released this year)

[image]

That's all we got for now from canon universe. I'll update this if the next hardcover comic of luke enters in detail about it when "Planet of Agostini" (spanish) editorial publishes it.

Comment: fwiw - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Shattered_Empire was released in 2015

Comment: Does that mean the two trees we see are related? Or that the two sprouts he has are related?

Comment: the sprouts are related, and being the same species and being force conscient, one could guess that they are as related as force users are.